# Webscrape heading and lists to a dataframe with rvest

Tags: r, dplyr, rvest, purrr

I would like to scrape the hyperlinks [on this webpage](http://www.secnav.navy.mil/fmc/fmb/Pages/Fiscal-Year-2019.aspx) into a dataframe with the columns shown below. The source page contains headings and lists of links.

- subject.heading (problem)
- hyperlink.title (OK)
- hyperlink (OK)

Getting the links and titles is straightforward (`html_node` "li" and "a"). I'm not clear how to incorporate the subject headings to the final dataframe.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

my.url <- read_html("http://www.secnav.navy.mil/fmc/fmb/Pages/Fiscal-Year-2019.aspx") %>% 
  html_nodes("#sharePointMainContent") 

hyperlink.title <- my.url %>% 
  html_nodes("li") %>% 
  html_text()

hyperlink <- my.url %>% 
  html_nodes("li") %>% 
  html_nodes("a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")

df <- tibble(title, hyperlink.title)
```

I can successfully scrape the headings, but cannot figure out how to incorporate them into the final dataframe properly.

```
subject.heading <- my.url %>% 
  html_nodes("h3") %>% 
  html_text() %>% str_trim()
```

Created on 2018-09-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That page has a weird structure, with tables inside the main table.

What I found to work is to iterate (`map_df()`) the cells of the parent table (identified by the `s4-wpcell-plain` class). Each cell contains another table, but we can simply extract what we are after, instead of relying on `html_table()`.

```r
library(tidyverse)    
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2


r <- read_html("http://www.secnav.navy.mil/fmc/fmb/Pages/Fiscal-Year-2019.aspx") %>% 
  html_node("#sharePointMainContent>div>table") %>% 
  html_nodes(".s4-wpcell-plain") %>% 
  map_df(~{
    heading <- .x %>% html_nodes('h3') %>% html_text() %>% str_trim()
    titles <- .x %>% html_nodes('li') %>% html_text()
    links <- .x %>% html_nodes('a') %>% html_attr("href")
    data_frame(heading, titles, links)
  })

r
#> # A tibble: 21 x 3
#>    heading                        titles                 links            
#>    <chr>                          <chr>                  <chr>            
#>  1 DEPARTMENT OF THE NAVY SUMMARY FY 19 DON Press Brief  http://www.secna…
#>  2 DEPARTMENT OF THE NAVY SUMMARY Supporting Exhibits    http://www.secna…
#>  3 DEPARTMENT OF THE NAVY SUMMARY Budget Highlights Book http://www.secna…
#>  4 DEPARTMENT OF THE NAVY SUMMARY The Bottom Line        http://www.secna…
#>  5 DEPARTMENT OF THE NAVY SUMMARY Report to Congress on… http://www.secna…
#>  6 DEPARTMENT OF THE NAVY SUMMARY Ship Building Plan SE… http://www.secna…
#>  7 MILITARY PERSONNEL PROGRAMS    Military Personnel, N… http://www.secna…
#>  8 MILITARY PERSONNEL PROGRAMS    Military Personnel, M… http://www.secna…
#>  9 MILITARY PERSONNEL PROGRAMS    Reserve Personnel, Na… http://www.secna…
#> 10 MILITARY PERSONNEL PROGRAMS    Reserve Personnel, Ma… http://www.secna…
#> # ... with 11 more rows
```

Created on 2018-09-04 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: I thought it might be strangely formatted, but am too much of a novice to know for sure. Your solution works well!

Comment: Your answer scrapes only the left side of the page. The column on the right that begins with "Procurement" is missing from your result.

Comment: It's probably the choice of `.s4-wpcell-plain` that only select the left side. I'm sure you can find a more appropriate selector.